# Add row information into Ajax.BeginForm Confirm message

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with several columns. The first column contains a location name and the last column contains a delete button. When I click any of the delete buttons, it currently displays the confirmation message "Are you sure you want to delete the location:" I want the end of the confirmation message to display the location name.

Here are the relevant bits in my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FirstAjax", "Configuration", null, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete the location:\n",
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnFailure = "deleteFailed",
                UpdateTargetId = "CustomLocations"
            },
            new { @id = "deleteLocation" }
            ))
            {
<div id="reportTblDiv">
      <table id="CustomLocations">
         <tbody>
             @foreach (var location in Model.LocationList)
                 {
                      <tr>
                           <td class="location">@location.LocationName</td>
                           <td>
<input type="submit" title=@Model.DeleteButton name="@location.LocationId" value="@Model.DeleteButton" />
</td>
</tr>
      }
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
}
```

How can I access the correct element in Model.LocationList from the line beginning with Confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the id of the first  to be the same as the name as the second . Add a handle to the submit in javascript to update the confirm message:

```
<td id=@location.LocationId class="location">@location.LocationName</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" title=@Model.DeleteButton name="@location.LocationId" value="@Model.DeleteButton" onclick="return btnDeleteClicked(this);"/>
</td>

     <script>
        function btnDeleteClicked(btnObject){

        var tLocation=$(btnObject).attr('name');
        var tCurrentMessage=$("#deleteLocation").data('ajax-confirm');

        $("#deleteLocation").data('ajax-confirm',tCurrentMessage + tLocation);

        return true;
       }
        </script>
```